# Question about inverse of CDF being a real analytic function

Tags: probability, inverse, analyticity

Let F: [0,a] -> [0,1] be a continuous, strictly increasing CDF.
Assume also F admists a continuous, positive pdf f.
Now define the inverse function h(x) as F(h(x))=x.
Is h real analytic?
If not, what conditions of F would be sufficient for h to be analytic?

Comment: The conditions you need are $F'>0$, and $F$ itself being real analytic. See [Is the inverse of a real analytic function still analytic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/359330)

Comment: I have F'>0, since f=F' is assumed positive.