# An explicit Taylor series of the inverse error function?

Tags: solution-verification, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, inverse-function, error-function

$\def\erf{\text{erf}}$

Browsing Wolfram Functions, we found the [**$n$th derivative of the inverse error function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/20/02/) and [of inverse gamma regularized](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/20/02/01/). Notice the [regularized](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQRegularized/)[$\,_2\text F_2$ hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F2/) and the [Kronecker delta function $\delta_{n},\delta_{n_1,n_2}$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/KroneckerDelta2/):

> $$\frac{d^n\erf^{-1}(z)}{dz^n}=\erf^{-1}(z)\delta_n+\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{\erf^{-1}(z)^2}\right)^n\sum_{j_2=0}^n\cdots\sum_{j_n=0}^n (-1)^{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n j_k}\delta_{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n(k-1)j_k,n-1}\left(n-1+\sum_{k=2}^n j_k\right)!\prod_{k=2}^n \frac1{j_k!}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi2^{k-1}e^{\erf^{-1}(z)^2}}{\erf^{-1}(z)^{k-1}k!}\right)^{j_k}\,_2\tilde{\text F}_2\left(\frac12,1;1-\frac k2,\frac{3-k}2;-\erf^{-1}(z)^2\right)^{j_k}\tag1$$
> with the Mathematica code:
> `D[InverseErf[z], {z, n}] == KroneckerDelta[n] InverseErf[z] + (Pi^(n/2)/2^n) E^(n InverseErf[z]^2) Sum[\[Ellipsis] Sum[KroneckerDelta[Sum[(i - 1) Subscript[j, i], {i, 2, n}], n - 1] (-1)^Sum[Subscript[j, i], {i, 2, n}] (n - 1 + Sum[Subscript[j, i], {i, 2, n}])! Product[(1/Subscript[j, i]!) ((2^(-1 + i) E^InverseErf[z]^2 Sqrt[Pi] InverseErf[z]^(1 - i))/i!)^Subscript[j, i] HypergeometricPFQRegularizedq[{1/2, 1}, {1 - i/2, (3 - i)/2}, -InverseErf[z]^2]^Subscript[j, i], {i, 2, n}], {Subscript[j, n], 0, n}], {Subscript[j, 2], 0, n}] /; Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0`

No reference, outside of Wolfram functions, for the formula was found, but [the top FAQ question](https://functions.wolfram.com/About/faq.html) implies that the formula has been verified with Mathematica. Therefore, the [analytic inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359330/is-the-inverse-of-a-real-analytic-function-still-analytic) function’s expansion about $z=\erf(1)=0.8427…$ should be:

$$\erf^{-1}(z)\mathop=^?\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-\erf(1))^n}{n!}\left(\delta_n+\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e\right)^n\sum_{j_2=0}^n\cdots\sum_{j_n=0}^n (-1)^{\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty j_k}\delta_{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n(k-1)j_k,n-1}\left(n-1+\sum_{k=2}^n j_k\right)!\prod_{k=2}^n \frac1{j_k!}\left(\frac{e\sqrt\pi2^{k-1}}{k!}\right)^{j_k}\,_2\tilde{\text F}_2\left(\frac12,1;1-\frac k2,\frac{3-k}2;-1\right)^{j_k}\right)= 1+\frac{e\sqrt\pi}2(z-\erf(1))+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(z-\erf(1))^n}{n!}\left(\delta_n+\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e\right)^n\sum_{j_2=0}^n\cdots\sum_{j_n=0}^n (-1)^{\sum\limits_{k=2}^nj_k}\delta_{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n(k-1)j_k,n-1}\left(n-1+\sum_{k=2}^n j_k\right)!\prod_{k=2}^n \frac1{j_k!}\left(\frac{e\sqrt\pi2^{k-1}}{k!}\right)^{j_k}\,_2\tilde{\text F}_2\left(\frac12,1;1-\frac k2,\frac{3-k}2;-1\right)^{j_k}\right) $$

There is a Mathematica formula [*download*](https://functions.wolfram.com/NB/InverseErf.nb) for $\erf^{-1}(z)$ to test the series expansion, but I do not have Mathematica. Also, the series about $z\to0$ may diverge since $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{e^{\erf^{-1}(z)^2}}{\erf^{-1}(z)^{k-1}}=\infty,k>1$ and the $\sum\limits_{j_2=0}^n\cdots\sum\limits_{j_n=0}^n (-1)^{\sum\limits\limits_{k=2}^n j_k}\delta_{\sum\limits\limits_{k=2}^n(k-1)j_k,n-1}\left(n-1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^n j_k\right)! $ reminds one of the [explicit series reversion formula in formula $(11)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html). If this series works, then we have an explicit series representation of the inverse error function and possibly an analytic continuation of the function.

> Does [**this $n$th derivative formula**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/20/02/) give the Taylor series coefficients $a_n$ for $\erf^{-1}(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}$? If so, how does one derive an explicit series about $z=0$?

This final question is optional, but @Steven Clark suggested the radius of convergence of $\erf^{-1}(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\erf^{-1}(z)\big|_{z=z_0}\text{ using }(1)$ is needed to know convergence and where an analytic continuation is possible.

Comment: In the very last question, do you mean $z_0=0$?

Comment: @Gary “about $z=0$“ means a Taylor series like in [formula 1  here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) where it uses “about $x=a$“, but not “about $a=\cdots$“. Right?

Comment: For reference, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B+SeriesCoefficient%5BInverseErf%5Bz%5D%2C+%7Bz%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+12%7D%5D gives the first few Maclaurin series coefficients for the inverse Erf function.

Answer (score 5):

*This is not an answer.*

Since we faced the problem of the inverse of the error function quite many years ago in my former research group, I give you the results for the inversion of
$$z=\text{erf}(x) \qquad \text{around} \qquad x=a$$

It write
$$\color{red}{x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi ^{\frac n2}\, e^{a^2 n} }{n!\,2^{\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor } }\,P_n(a)\,\big[z-\text{erf}(a)\big]^n}$$ the first polynomials being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(a) \\
 0 & a \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & a \\
 3 & 4 a^2+1 \\
 4 & a \left(12 a^2+7\right) \\
 5 & 96 a^4+92 a^2+7 \\
 6 & a \left(480 a^4+652 a^2+127\right) \\
 7 & 5760 a^6+10224 a^4+3480 a^2+127 \\
 8 & a \left(40320 a^6+88848 a^4+44808 a^2+4369\right) \\
 9 & 645120 a^8+1703808 a^6+1161168 a^4+204328 a^2+4369 \\
 10 & a \left(5806080 a^8+17914752 a^6+15561936 a^4+4161288 a^2+243649\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$ which show interesting patterns. After reading you post, it is almost obvious that these polynomials correspond to some hypergeometric functions (which I did not identify)

For $a=1$, the $P_n(1)$ generate the sequence
$$\{1,1,1,5,19,195,1259,19591,178345,3718793,43687705,1141949277,16433602763\}$$ not found in $OEIS$.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain a recurrence for the $P_n(a)$'s using the identity $$
\left( {\int {\operatorname{erf}^{ - 1} (z)dz} } \right)\left( {\frac{d}{{dz}}\operatorname{erf}^{ - 1} (z)} \right) =  - \frac{1}{2}\,?
$$

Comment: @Gary. This would be more than great ! As I wrote, this is an old work which, in my opinion, has not been finished (even if the above has been more than useful). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There is downloadable Mathematica Notebook code for formulas on [this page](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/20/02/). It is optional, but could you test the Taylor series formula, from the question, in Mathematica from it if it is there?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I verified for $a=1$ the $P_n(1)$ generate the sequence $\{1,1,1,5,19,195,1259,19591,178345,3718793,43687705,1141949277,16433602763\}$ using Mathematica which you can also do using WolframAlpha (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BSeriesCoefficient%5B++++InverseErf%5Bz%5D%2C+%7Bz%2C+Erf%5B1%5D%2C++++++n%7D%5D%2F%28%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28n%2F2%29+E%5En%2F%28n%21+2%5EFloor%5B%28n+%2B+1%29%2F2%5D+%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+12%7D%5D).

Comment: @TymaGaidash My comment was only meant to illustrate the results in the answer above seem to be correct. I'm not sure I understand your question. Is it about the radius of convergence of the Taylor series?

Comment: @StevenClark In short, Wolfram functions has the formula for the $n$th derivative of the inverse error function [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/20/02). Since the function is analytic, we can use the linked formula to maybe expand the $n$th derivative in $\text{erf}^{-1}(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}\frac {d^n}{dz^n}\text{erf}^{-1}(z)\big|_{z=z_0}$. Does this work?

Comment: @TymaGaidash If a formula for $f^{(n)}(z)$ is correct, why could it not be used in the Taylor series $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n$? Are you asking if the formula for $\frac{d^n\, \text{erf}^{-1}(z)}{dz^n}$ is correct? Wolfram seems to imply it's valid for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ in which case the relevant question would seem to be what is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $\text{erf}^{-1}(z)$.

Comment: @StevenClark I edited the comment before your reply, so it may not show the $(z-z_0)^n$ for you. We should check to see if the series expansion using the $n$th derivative formula works, but if Wolfram implies that it is valid for complex $z$, then checking the radius of convergence is the next logical step. You are correct.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I've read the radius of convergence of a Taylor series can be zero, but I've also read the Taylor series  of an analytic function has a radius of convergence of infinity (see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_Series_of_Analytic_Function_has_infinite_Radius_of_Convergence).